# Are there more than two possible outcomes for this function ?

Tags: javascript

I have a function that is supposed to be used to randomly redirect to another page:

```
function () {
        var rand_exp = ['v', 'a'];
        var pick_exp = function(expType) {
                    return expType[Math.floor(Math.random()*expType.length)];
                 }
        if (pick_exp(rand_exp) === 'v') {
           window.location.replace("experiment_v.html");
        } else if (pick_exp(rand_exp) === 'a') {
           window.location.replace("experiment_a.html");
       }
    }
```

I've tested this several times and 1 of 3 things seem to happen, it will either redirect to one of the two clauses in the if and else if statements or it will redirect to the page the above javascript is imbedded in, in which case I just have a blank screen, is this to be expected ?

Comment: you can omit the second if `} else if (pick`, beause you get only two alternatives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured I'd turn my comment above into a proper answer, and the short version of that answer is yes, there are more than two possible outcomes.

**Longer Version**

Your function `pick_exp` is correctly implemented such that it will select an element of the input array. The problem is that you are calling it more than once and expecting the elements of the array to be evenly represented in the results.

In the first condition, you call `pick_exp` the first time. The result might be 'a' or 'v', which would result in the expression being true or false with 50% probability for each case. If it was false, you then call it again, and it picks a *new* value, which might be 'a' or 'v' with equal probability independent or what the result was the last time you called it, so there's a 50% chance that the second expression will result in false as well, which means you return from the function with no redirect occurring. The chance of actually redirecting should be about 50% overall.

The fixed code would look like this:

```
function () {
    var rand_exp = ['v', 'a'];
    var pick_exp = function (expType) {
        expType[Math.floor(Math.random()*expType.length)];
    };

    var result = pick_exp(rand_exp);

    if (result === 'v') {
       window.location.replace("experiment_v.html");
    } else if (result === 'a') {
       window.location.replace("experiment_a.html");
   }
}
```

You can do it without the function and get something like this:

```
function () {
    var rand_exp = ['v', 'a'];
    var pick_exp = rand_exp[Math.floor(Math.random()*rand_exp.length)];

    if (pick_exp === 'v') {
       window.location.replace("experiment_v.html");
    } else if (pick_exp === 'a') {
       window.location.replace("experiment_a.html");
   }
}
```

The above code results in exactly two possible paths: `'v' -> experiment_v.html` and `a -> experiment_a.html`.

Alternatively, you can use the result directly:

```
function () {
    var rand_exp = ['v', 'a'];

    window.location.replace("experiment_" + rand_exp[Math.floor(Math.random()*rand_exp.length)] + ".html");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Are there more than two possible outcomes for this function ?

No, your universal set is limited to `['v', 'a']`.

And this line

```
return expType[Math.floor(Math.random()*expType.length)];
```

will only return 'v' or 'a', since `expType.length` is **2**

[Math.random](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random) returns a fraction value between 0 and 1 (less than 1).

When you multiply that value with 2 (`expType.length`), output will always be less than 2, on top of which if you do `Math.floor`, then output will be either 0 or 1.

Comment: any idea as to why it will sometimes fail to redirect ?

Comment: Is it possible for you to share a fiddle showing the failure to redirect?

Comment: I use the library http://www.jspsych.org/ so I'm not sure how to mimic all that functionality on fiddle but, I replaced the `if` and `else if` statements with `var exp = pick_exp(rand_exp);
    window.location.replace(`experiment_${exp}.html`);` and it looks to not fail anymore ...

Comment: The issue is that you are calling pick_exp independently in each of the test conditions. You need to call it once to generated a seeded result and then test the result. In other words, it's possible that neither condition will return true because the function would pick the other expression at that time.